# phpMyAdmin - make user which only sees databases they create

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am aware of how to grant a user access to only one database using phpMyAdmin, and I am aware of how to give a user access to create a new database using phpMyAdmin (using the Create privilege).

However, granting the Create privilege to a user also allows them to see all databases. Is there a way to allow users to create databases, but only view the databases that they have created?

I realise that this can be done with actual PHP / MySQL queries when creating the database (i.e. `GRANT`, also see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/309401/dont-list-the-databases-which-dont-belong-to-the-user)), however can it be done using only the phpMyAdmin interface (thus I also don't want answers involving a *different* interface)?

Answer (score 0):

The CREATE privilege needs to be able to determine if a MySQL database name already exists or not, before a new database can be created, as you can't have two different databases with the same name.

So read access to list/enumerate all databases is a requirement.

From a user experience point of view I am sure you could patch phpMyAdmin to only list the database a user has access to, but then you'll get enquiries why they can't create a new database `<name>` since it clearly doesn't exist yet but the create fails with a *"database already exists error"*.
So that sounds like a Bad Idea™ to me...